# Solve the triple integral $\int_{0}^{c}\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a}e^{-x-y-z}dxdydz$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve the following...
$$\int_{0}^{c}\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a}e^{-x-y-z}dxdydz$$

I understand how to solve triple integrals but this exponent is stressing me out. How does one go about finding the integral of this? Is integration by parts needed?

I do not necessarily need a solution for all three integrals, but if someone could at least explain how to solve the first one that would put me on the right track.

Comment: Hmm, you might need to find some help if math is stressing you out: it's supposed to be fun, even when you can't solve it!

Comment: . . . touché . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\int_0^c \int_0^b \int_0^a e^{-x-y-z}\,dx\,dy\,dz
= \int_0^c \int_0^b \int_0^a e^{-z}e^{-y}e^{-x}\,dx\,dy\,dz
= \int_0^c \Big(e^{-z} \int_0^b \Big(e^{-y} \int_0^a e^{-x}\,dx\Big)dy\Big)dz
$$